# Passing a value to a Windows PowerShell function in command line

Tags: powershell

```
param($scriptParameter = '')

 function UpdateVersion($VersionNumber)
 {
     write-host "Version is $VersionNumber"
 } 
 function clean
 {
     write-host "Calling Cleaning Function"
 } 
 function HelpList
 {
     write-host "Calling HelpList Function"
 } 
switch ($scriptParameter)
{
  Clean{clean}
  UpdateVersion{UpdateVersion $VersionNumber}
  DEFAULT{HelpList}
}


 PS C:\Workspace\dev>> .\deploymentScript.ps1 UpdateVersion "18.4.1.9"
```

Question : $ScriptParameter accepting only one argument "UpdateVersion". Not able to pass VersionNumber. $VersionNumber is getting blank

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a second parameter for version number.

```
param($scriptParameter = '', $VersionNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. It helps